# How to handle multiple scrollintoview in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, js-scrollintoview

I need to scroll a page to specific div which contains specific word "Load more" which has multiple text in multiple div. Here is my code

```
List<WebElement> Loadmore = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Load more')]"));
    for(int i=0;i<Loadmore.size();i++)
    {
        String Loadmoreid = Loadmore.get(i).getAttribute("id");
        WebElement Loadmoretxt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, '"+Loadmoreid+"')]"));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", Loadmoretxt);
        WebElement Loadmoreweb = driver.findElement(By.id(Loadmoreid));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(Loadmoreweb).click().perform();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
Actions action = new Actions(Loadmoretxt);
action.moveToElement(target);
action.perform();
```

Comment: There are 2 loadmore link it is hitting 2nd link only not first link & i have change your code to Actions action = new Actions(driver); action.moveToElement(Loadmoretxt); action.click().perform(); because if i use your code it shows error

Comment: use this xpath for first element selection.
WebElement Loadmoretxt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, '"+Loadmoreid+"')][1]"));
instead of action.click().perform(); simply use action.perform() and Loadmoretxt.click();

Comment: It's not working page is not scrolling to text Loadmore to visible i think that is an issues. It is showing Element <div> is not clickable at point (158, 8) this error